# wp_query - Exclude the first thumbnail from lazy loading on archives

Tags: php, wp-query, post-thumbnails

I have a function that change loading="lazy" to loading="eager" from the first thumbnail in categories and tags.
The problem is that this function removes the post thumbnails from posts and pages.
I tried to conditionally exclude posts and pages with !is_single() && !is_page() but with no effect:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', function( $attrs ) {
    if ( !is_single() && !is_page() && is_front_page() && is_archive() && is_search() ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->current_post === 0 )
        $attrs['loading'] = 'eager';
        return $attrs;
    }
} );
```

Comment: Filters ***always*** return something. If you do not return something, it's assumed you meant `null`. Try adding a type hint `: array` to the function and you'll notice it triggers a PHP fatal error when your if statements are false because it does not return a value. Indenting the code correctly will make it clearer that this is the problem

Comment: Do I need to change add_filter to add_action?

Comment: No, that would make no difference. Notice that the function only returns a value in a very specific scenario, and only in that scenario. This is wrong, it must ***always*** return a value in every situation, even if you don't want to change or add to `$attrs` then it must still return it unmodified. This is unavoidable. E.g. what if the current post is not 0? Or it's a singular page? There is no `return` statement there, so PHP assumes `null` which is an empty value

Comment: Another way to look at it, is by adding `else { }` clauses to your if checks, what happens in those? Right now the answer is `???????` and the result is empty values, nothing.

Comment: You mean changing the values === 0 to < 2 for example?

Comment: no, read the function line by line and you'll see that it only returns a value in one specific situation, but in the other situations it does not return at all, and it must return a value. No value -> no attributes -> no post thumbnails. WordPress is giving you `$attrs` so that you have an opportunity to change it, but you must return it when you are finished, even if you do not make a change. Right now you only return in a single place with `return $attrs;`. You need to always return, not just when its the first post in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Filters must **always** return a value. If you do not return a value, it's the same as returning an empty value, `null`, etc. This is always the first parameter, or a modified/replacement version of it.

So this:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', function( $attrs ) {
    if ( !is_single() && !is_page() && is_front_page() && is_archive() && is_search() ) {
        global $wp_query;

        if ( $wp_query->current_post === 0 )
            $attrs['loading'] = 'eager';
            return $attrs;
        }
    }
);
```

Is the same as this:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', function( $attrs ) {
    if ( !is_single() && !is_page() && is_front_page() && is_archive() && is_search() ) {
        global $wp_query;

        if ( $wp_query->current_post === 0 )
            $attrs['loading'] = 'eager';
            return $attrs;
        } else {
            // I don't want post thumbnails, return nothing
            return null;
        }
    }
    // I don't want post thumbnails, return nothing
    return null;
);
```

Remember, a filter is WordPress handing you a value temporarily, then you handing it back to WordPress, allowing you to change it.

What your code does is the equivalent of handing it back with a change if it meets certain criteria ( changing lazy to eager ), but if it doesn't meet those criteria instead of handing it back unchanged, you've set it on fire and thrown it away.

If we add  type hinting to the function, it make the mistake more obvious with a PHP fatal error:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', function( $attrs ) : array {
```

The function needs to return a value, and by doing this we tell PHP it always returns an array. As a result when a post that is not the first post, or a page that is not a search archive etc loads, the function doesn't `return` anything and it will generate a PHP fatal rather than a warning.

You should also have noticed that the PHP error log will contain PHP warnings for this function.

To fix this, you need to change the filter so that it always returns a value. You get no post thumbnails because the filter return nothing. If you don't want to change the attributes, return them as is with `return $attrs;`. Filters **always** return something

Comment: The function return fatal error when I include return null;

Comment: I added `return null` to demonstrate what your original code is equivalent to, it is not a copy paste answer. Filters always give you something to filter as the first parameter. You then return that having modified or not modified it. Your code only returns it when it's modified, that is why your post thumbnails are missing. Also notice I said it would cause a PHP fatal error if you added `: array {` without fixing your issue. If you look in your PHP error log you'll see the error message complaining that it expected an array but `null` was returned instead

Comment: How to fix this issue? I'm sorry because my skills are very basic.

Comment: if I hand you an object and say _"this is you opportunity to change it, give me it back when you're done"_, you always hand me it back. The same is true of filters, you must always return what you were given. You were given `$attrs`, which will become what your function returns. If you do not return anything then `$attrs` will be undefined, empty, missing. Your function only returns when it is the first post on a particular type of archive, aka when you want to make it eager loading, this is bad, it must _always_ return something, even if it's unchanged

Comment: Also note I will not be adding a copy paste code solution. A beginner level understanding of PHP is required to use this answer.

Comment: I trying another more elegant approach to change attributes of the first two thumbnails on archives, search etc. and to change the first featured thumbnail only on single and pages with something like this: if ( $wp_query->current_post < 2 && $wp_query->is_singular === 0). Does this make sense? If not, please hint me for the equivalent solution.

Comment: The `if` statement is not the problem, it's what happens when it is _not_ the first post. You forgot to return the attributes. Changing the if statement will make no difference. The problem is that you are only returning when it's the first thumbnail and you want to make a change. You never return the unmodified value when you don't want to make a change. I'm going to leave this now as I've described it many times in many ways and you're still looking at the wrong thing.